# Is this proof of $\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k} $ valid?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, discrete-calculus

I want to show that :
$$\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1} = \frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!}$$

Here is my proof : $\forall 1\leq k\leq n$ :

$$\begin{align}
\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1} &= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n+1-k)!} \tag1 \\[4pt]
&=\frac{n!(n+1-k)}{k!(n+1-k)!} +\frac{n!k}{k!(n+1-k)!} \tag2 \\[4pt]
&= \frac{n!(n+1-k+k)}{k!(n+1-k)!} \tag3 \\[4pt]
&=\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!} \tag4 \\[4pt]
&=\binom{n+1}{k} \tag5
\end{align}$$

And normally I avoided problem of factorial not defined since $k\leq n$.

Do you think this is correct ?

Thank you a lot

EDIT  : Thank you everyone and especially Riemann and Jean-Claude Arbault since it is not defined for $k=0$...

Comment: I think it's fine, except that you should assume $k\ge 1$, because $\binom{n}{k-1}$ may not be defined if $k=0$.

Comment: this looks good to me

Comment: Your title should probably be ${n\choose k}+{n\choose k-1}={n+1\choose k}$ as that's the more meaningful expression.  But your proof, which is just arithmetical manipulation, is just fine.

Comment: It's done ! Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes it's correct**
$$\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}$$
$$=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}+\frac{n!}{(n+1-k)!\cdot (k-1)!}$$
$$=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot (k-1)!}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n+1-k}\right)$$
$$=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot (k-1)!}\left(\frac{n+1-k+k}{k(n+1-k)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{n!(n+1)}{(n+1-k)!\cdot k!}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1-k)!\cdot k!}$$
$$=\binom{n+1}{k}$$
Here we made the assumption that $k\ne 0$

Comment: One must be careful with boundaries. (a well-known trap for induction proofs, for instance, though it's not the case here) As stated by Rieman above, there is an error in the proof. For $k=0$, $n\choose k-1$ is not defined. And even if you care to define it to be zero, $(-1)!$ is not defined, and there is no way you are going to define it to be zero.

Comment: It's understood that $k\ne0$

Comment: Not in the question. And it's a proof verification question, so you have to consider what is correct, and what is not. I.e., when you write "yes it's correct", you are wrong ;-)

Comment: Btw isn't $(-1)!=(0-1)!=\Gamma(0)?$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut i see...thanks

Comment: Yes, and it's not defined, and certainly not $0$. Have a look at the curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: But $$\Gamma(0)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$$

Comment: And the integral is divergent.

Comment: If it's correct, then why did you show a (slightly) different way of doing it?

Comment: original proof is correct. this extra proof provided is only slightly different and unnecessary... scratching my head trying to figure out why it was offerred up?